# lagrange interpolation how to include the interval

Tags: c++, interpolation

I have to have this input. Unfortunately, I do not know how to include the interval a, b. Please help

number of interpolation nodes,
a, b, a < b,
values ​​of the function f at nodal points.
Expected output:
Lagrange polynomial being an interpolation of a given function in "evenly determined" interpolation nodes.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double xtab[1000], ytab[1000], results[1000];
    cout<<"Enter how many x and y"<<endl;
    int quantity;
    cin>>quantity;
    cout<<"Provide an argument to calculate"<<endl;
    int value;
    cin>>value;
    for(int i=0; i<quantity; i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter x number"<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>xtab[i];
        cout<<"enter y number"<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>ytab[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<quantity; i++)
    {
        results[i]=ytab[i];
        for(int k=0; k<quantity; k++)
        {
            if(xtab[i]!=xtab[k])
            {
                results[i]*=(1.000*value-xtab[k]);
            }
        }
        for(int k=0; k<quantity; k++)
        {
            if(xtab[i]!=xtab[k])
            {
                results[i]/=(1.000*xtab[i] -xtab[k]);
            }
        }

    }
    double sum =0;
    cout<<"---------------"<<endl<<"The value of the expression is: ";
    for(int i=0; i<quantity; i++)
    {
        if(i!=0)
            cout<<" + ";
        suma+=(results[i]*1.000);
        cout<<results[i];
    }
    cout<<" = "<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know either. You use nowhere `a, b`, how we should figure out what you are achieving?

Comment: I can't find any example with the interpolation interval in c ++

Comment: What's the point of `1.000*value` (which is equal to `value`) and the likes? Did you meant `1'000 * value` (or `1000 * value`)?